# What means third parameter in fstream open function

Tags: c++, function, c++17, fstream

What does mean the third parameter in the fstream open function? I tried to search it on the web, but there's no clear explanation about overloaded versions with three parameters.
This is from fstream file:

```
void open(const char* _Filename, ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out,
    int _Prot = (int) ios_base::_Openprot) { // open a C stream with specified mode
```

If this parameter is really necessary for the programmer in some cases, or it just for realisation conveniences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as the C++ standard is concerned, [there is no third parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open). Your implementation may have a default parameter for the sake of some implementation-specific convenience, but the C++ standard has no such parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The 3rd parameter is documented in [Microsoft's documentation for the `basic_fstream::open()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-fstream-class#open):

> Parameters
>
> *_Filename*
>   The name of the file to open.
>
> *_Mode*
>   One of the enumerations in [ios_base::openmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/ios-base-class#openmode).
>
> ***_Prot*
>
>   The default file opening protection, equivalent to the `shflag` parameter in [_fsopen, _wfsopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fsopen-wfsopen).**

> The argument `shflag` is a constant expression consisting of one of the following manifest constants, defined in Share.h.
>
> _SH_COMPAT
>   Sets Compatibility mode for 16-bit applications.
>
> _SH_DENYNO
>   Permits read and write access.
>
> _SH_DENYRD
>   Denies read access to the file.
>
> _SH_DENYRW
>   Denies read and write access to the file.
>
> _SH_DENYWR
>   Denies write access to the file.

The value of `std::ios_base::_Openprot` is defined as `_SH_DENYNO`.